# splitting c-string by putting 0's (segfault)

Tags: c, split, c-strings, string-literals

A very simple C program: I want to put 0's at some points in a string to obtain sub-strings. But at the first try I get segmentation fault on execution:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main() {
        char *a = "eens kijken of we deze string kunnen splitten";
        a[4] = '\0'; // this causes the segfault
        char *b = a[5]; // sort of guessed this can't work...
        printf("%s", a);
}
```

So the main question: why the segfault at `a[4] = '\0';` Second I'd like to split this string with the least amount of code, based on string-index...

Comment: In C all string literals are arrays of characters, and they're not allowed to be modified (the arrays are effectively read-only). That's why you should always use `const char *` when pointing to such strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to change a string literal.

```
char *a = "eens kijken of we deze string kunnen splitten";
```

String literals are immutable in C. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspeciﬁed whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undeﬁned.**

Instead declare a character array

```
char a[] = "eens kijken of we deze string kunnen splitten";
```

Also in this declaration

```
char *b = a[5];
```

there is a typo. Should be

```
char *b = &a[5];
```

or

```
char *b = a + 5;
```

Comment: So it is just a matter of writing a[] or * a that defines whether it is a constant char*, right? because essentially they are both just pointers (a[] and *a)

Comment: @Niels For starters arrays are not pointers. Secondly in the first case the pointer points to a string literal that gas the static storage duration. In the second case when an array is used the elements of the string literals are copied in elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `a` pointer to a string literal.
These constants are stored in a non-writable section of the resulting executable.
Trying to write anything into that area will cause a segfault.

A string array (`char a[]='literal';`) will put the string into the right place and allow writing.

edit:
Your syntax, (de)referencing a char * is correct, but the compiler will treat it differently.